# touchmove event not always triggered on Chrome for Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I am trying to make this [map](http://map.f4-group.com) work on a touchscreen (WebGL must be enabled).

With Firefox on Android it works fine. But with Chrome, initially, if I touch the screen it works, but if I release the screen and touch it again quickly (less than 1 or 2 seconds after I released the screen), no `touchmove`event is triggered. If I wait long enough, I receive the `touchmove`event correctly.

Here is some relevant code (sorry, I cannot provide the complete source code):

```
canvas.on('touchstart', function() {
    //init drag
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
canvas.on('touchmove', function() {
    //move the map
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
canvas.on('touchend', function() {
    //stop drag
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

I tried with and without `preventDefault`or `return false`, with no success. What did I miss ?

You can reproduce this issue with [Chrome for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome), enabling WebGL first (go to `chrome://flags` and enable WebGL), [here](http://map.f4-group.com) or [here for a more beautiful view](http://map.f4-group.com/#lon=37.6176622&lat=55.7505164&zoom=18&camera.theta=50.174&camera.phi=-2.005).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It feels like your app is blocking on touchEnd. The touchmove works again right after the address bar is updated why new coordinates. Could it be something wrong with the window.location.replace ? 
I experienced a similar blocking on a website using hardware accelerated features during a window.location.replace.

Comment: Disabling URL update indeed fixes the issue! As I already use `replaceState`, I must find another workaround.

Comment: Btw, there is the same bug on Chrome desktop.

Comment: Thanks for testing on Chrome desktop, I do not have the hardware to test it.

Comment: Notice that on my Safari (mac) the website is telling me that I don't have WebGL, but It works well actually.

Comment: `replaceState` is not the issue, but a slow function computing the new URL...It works without WebGL, but you miss the main interest of this map: try this link for example http://map.f4-group.com/#lon=2.3497233&lat=48.8532939&zoom=19&camera.theta=51.893&camera.phi=12.032

Comment: This is now fixed and online. Thanks!